# Positioning tooltips with CSS

Tags: css, positioning, tooltip, window-resize

My issue concerns tooltip positioning.

The script that I adapted uses absolute positioning to place the tooltips a couple of em's from the link. That works great, for large screens.

However, when the screen shrinks, sometimes the text appears near the edge of the browser, and the tooltip just hangs there, over the edge.

To combat this, I came up with my own hack-ey solution: Simply include relative positioning rules for smaller screen widths, with an @media screen and (max-width: 480px) thing that I don't fully understand. This works, but it's far from elegant.

Ideally, the tooltip would get "pushed" by the edge of the screen, as the screen edges in. I have no idea how to achieve this, though.

Hopefully, that makes sense.

Anyway, [here's a link to the page that I've used this all on](http://huttj.com/about/) (the tooltip text has dotted underlines), and [here's the CSS behind it](http://pastie.org/4335468).

Comment: Are you okay with using JavaScript/jQuery for this?

Comment: I suppose I would be, but that introduces even more code that I am not familiar with. The percentage width that Rob suggested seems to work great when used with "float:left." I had previously used it with absolute positioning, and it had the overflow problem.

With relative positioning, it seems alright.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using em, use percentage, but you have to remember that percentage will always be percent of the parent of the tooltip's size.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but, for the reason you stated, it's not a functional solution. The parent is a short link, so this makes them much too narrow.

Comment: Actually, I just tried it with a negative margin of 100%, and it seems to work perfectly. I'll do some further testing, but this definitely seems to be an improvement for the smaller screen sizes. Thanks!